# Problems getting my sinatra based app to work on Heroku

Tags: ruby, git, heroku, rubygems, sinatra

I made a simple Sinatra app to run a homepage. It's already working on my computer. Now I wanted to host it at heroku, but I can't manage it to make it run. I am not really familiar with concepts like "Gemfile" or "Procfile".

My ruby app requires Sinatra, haml and sinatra/r18n. My gemfile looks like this:

```
source :rubygems
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'thin'
gem 'sinatra-r18n'
gem 'haml'
```

My Procfile looks like this:

```
web: bundle exec ruby app.rb -p $PORT
```

My app.rb starts like this:

```
# app.rb

require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/r18n'
require 'haml'

enable :sessions

helpers do
  def set_lang (langcode)
...
```

Other files in the directory include the Gemfile.lock which was created through bundle install if I remember correctly and folders for "r18n", "public", "views".

If I start the application on heroku the "heroku ps" command says the application is "up" but if I use "heroku open" I get an "Internal Server Error".

Here is the "heroku logs" after I push it to heroku:

```
2012-09-15T19:34:54+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2012-09-15T19:35:01+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v13 created by -@gmail.com
2012-09-15T19:35:01+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy bebc79e by -@gmail.com
2012-09-15T19:35:01+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2012-09-15T19:35:01+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2012-09-15T19:35:02+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec ruby app.rb -p 54979`
2012-09-15T19:35:05+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2012-09-15T19:35:05+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-09-15T19:35:06+00:00 app[web.1]: == Sinatra/1.1.0 has taken the stage on 20773 for production with backup from Thin
2012-09-15T19:35:06+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Thin web server (v1.4.1 codename Chromeo)
2012-09-15T19:35:06+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Maximum connections set to 1024
2012-09-15T19:35:06+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:20773, CTRL+C to stop
2012-09-15T19:35:06+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Stopping ...
2012-09-15T19:35:06+00:00 app[web.1]:
2012-09-15T19:35:06+00:00 app[web.1]: == Sinatra has ended his set (crowd applauds)
2012-09-15T19:35:07+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
```

Has anybody an idea what's going wrong here? Maybe something obvious if you are more familiar to the used concepts. I also would take hints for material that helps me to solve the problem, but until now all my googling/reading didn't help.

**Update 28-09**
I now removed the Procfile from code and still get the "Internal Server Error". Here is some more log which should include the crash:

```
 2012-09-28T18:04:50+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
 2012-09-28T18:04:58+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e production -p 30813`
 2012-09-28T18:05:01+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/views/start.haml:1:in `evaluate_source'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:209:in `instance_eval'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Encoding::CompatibilityError - incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8:
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:209:in `evaluate_source'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:127:in `evaluate'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:144:in `cached_evaluate'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/haml.rb:24:in `evaluate'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:76:in `render'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:452:in `render'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/app.rb:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:370:in `haml'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1032:in `call'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1032:in `block in compile!'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:620:in `instance_eval'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:620:in `route_eval'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:656:in `block in process_route'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:653:in `catch'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:604:in `block (2 levels) in route!'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:653:in `process_route'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:603:in `block in route!'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:602:in `each'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:602:in `route!'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:530:in `block in call!'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:706:in `instance_eval'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:741:in `dispatch!'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:706:in `block in invoke'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:706:in `catch'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 heroku[router]: GET fierce-crag-6255.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=73ms status=500 bytes=30
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:706:in `invoke'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:516:in `call'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:530:in `call!'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1168:in `synchronize'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:20:in `call'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1142:in `block in call'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `block in pre_process'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `pre_process'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:38:in `receive_data'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `catch'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1142:in `call'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:86:in `start'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:185:in `run_command'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:151:in `run!'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `load'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
 2012-09-28T18:05:02+00:00 app[web.1]: 212.90.85.15 - - [28/Sep/2012 18:05:02] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 30 0.0591
 2012-09-28T18:05:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 212.90.85.15 - - [28/Sep/2012 18:05:03] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1416 0.0109
 2012-09-28T18:05:03+00:00 heroku[router]: GET fierce-crag-6255.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=13ms status=200 bytes=1416
 2012-09-28T18:05:03+00:00 heroku[router]: GET fierce-crag-6255.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=1416
 2012-09-28T18:05:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 212.90.85.15 - - [28/Sep/2012 18:05:03] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1416 0.0026
```

Comment: You have `Starting process with command \`bundle exec ruby app.rb -p 54979\`` and `Sinatra/1.1.0 has taken the stage on 20773 for production with backup from Thin` – different port umbers so something's wrong there. Are you setting the port in your app file with `set :port, 20773` by any chance?

Comment: Oops, that should be numbers, not umbers.

Comment: You've provided the log from before the error occurred, but not after. Can you paste your log *after* you've browsed the app in your browser and received the "Internal Server Error" message? It should include a nice big stack trace.

Comment: @matt Thanks for the hint. But no, I am not setting any port within the app. I am not sure why the port differs there.

Comment: @canton7 Okay, thanks. I posted a much longer log now, this should imclude the crash..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yay, I just figured it out myself. I should have put more attention to the `Encoding::CompatibilityError - incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8:` in the heroku logs. I removed all the German umlauts and now it is working. The problem now with the encoding is adressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534517/characters-encoding-wrong-in-terminal-using-git). I hope I can figure this out somehow. Thanks everyone anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You do not necessarily need a Procfile. If you want to let heroku run your app in a default way, just remove it. Instead, add a `config.ru` file in a way like in [this small example](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack#frameworks) from heroku.

Comment: Thank you, you were right about this. I only added this, because I hoped it would solve my problem.