# Characters encoding wrong in terminal using git

Tags: git, encoding, ubuntu-12.04

Any time I try to make a "git diff" command to see a file change, it shows me problem in special characters, like accented ones, but if I see the file with "cat" it shows me everything ok. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

ex:

```
WHERE  `T<C3><A9>cnico` IS NOT NULL
```

I tried to put these lines in .gitconfig, close terminal e open again, but still didn't work.

```
[i18n]
    logoutputencoding = utf8
    commitencoding = utf8
```

Anyone have other suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure of your git version.

For [Ubuntu12.0.4 (precise), the package search for git](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/devel/git-core) indicates a:

```
git-core (1:1.7.9.5-1)
```

And i18n issues have been addressed in git1.7.10+ (see "[git, msysgit, accents, utf-8, the definitive answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854967/git-msysgit-accents-utf-8-the-definitive-answers/5855213#5855213)").